# If para datediff Mysql

Tags: if, sql-select, mysql

Estou praticando algumas coisas, e me surgiu uma duvida. criei uma tabela e nela quero controlar tempos de suspensão, na qual, faço um insert com uma data para suspensao (preenchendo uma coluna chamada "data_suspensao") e posteriormente coloco uma data de ativação na coluna "data_ativacao" e com isso determino o período de suspensão de um serviço. Funciona bem para os casos em que tenho as duas datas, mas gostaria de realizar o calculo para datas sem ativação para relatorios de "dias suspensos". Minha ideia é atribuir para onde a data_ativacao = null, 0 e utilizei o (ifnull) pois quero mostrar que não a data de ativação, e no select na coluna "Dias Suspenso" gostaria de usar um if. Minha ideia é algo do tipo if(data_ativacao = null, usar_data_atual) else (data_ativacao) e então ter uma data para usar o "datediff", fiz a query da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT id_contrato as 'Contrato',

data_suspensao as 'Data da Aticao',

ifnull(data_ativacao,0) as 'Data da Aticao',

datediff(data_ativacao,data_suspensao) as 'Dias Suspenso'

FROM contrato_suspensao where data_suspensao >= '2021-09-01';
```

Pensei em algo nesse sentido:

```
datediff(if(data_ativacao = null,'2021-09-27',data_ativacao),data_suspensao) as 'Dias Suspenso'
```

Se a `data_ativacao = null` usar uma data que que eu passar (ou até alguma função para pegar o dia atual) se não utilizar a `data_ativacao` que estiver lá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datediff(if(data_ativacao is null,now(), data_ativacao),data_suspensao) as 'Dias Suspenso'

Após algumas pesquisas fiz esta solução e funcionou.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Dado que sua solução funcionou, você pode colocar essa resposta como "correta" na sua pergunta.

Comment: foi rapido nem deu tempo de ler :)